# Can Content-Range header be sent in a HTTP 200 OK Response

Tags: http-headers

My caching server refuses to cache a 200 OK response when it has a Content-Range Header. This was the RFC2616-compliant implementation.

However, a requirement came to cache the 200 OK response even if it has the Content-Range header. Is that allowed or does it violate the RFC-spec?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN docs for `Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range):

> The server can also ignore the `Range` header and return the whole document with a 200 status code.

Similarly, the [MDN docs for range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) state under **Partial request responses**:

> - In case of no support of range requests, the 200 OK status is sent back from a server.

In other words, the browser can assume that the server *does not* support partial responses if it receives a `200` in response to a `Range` header. At the moment, Chrome does just this. Even if you send the entire document back, if Chrome receives a `200` when it requests part of a video, the playback bar/seekbar *does not work*.

As to whether the `Content-Range` is actually *allowed*, I haven't found any documentation yet. From what I understand, the `Content-Range` header makes no sense if you send a `200` in response to a `Range` header as you are supposed to send the entire file. In other words, it can be ignored; it is only meaningful with a `206`.

To answer your other question, you can therefore cache the `200` regardless of whether `Content-Range` is present. A `206` with `Content-Range` may also be cached:

> A 206 response is cacheable by default; i.e., unless otherwise indicated by explicit cache controls (see Section 4.2.2 of [RFC7234]).

-- last paragraph in [Section 4.1 of RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1).